# Check if in multiple columns there are NaN values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would check if in a dataframe, all rows from index columns 1 to 10 are NaN values.
Here the code tried

```
if df.iloc[:, [1,10]].isna().any(1):
    print('NaN values')
```

But I got the same error

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try via for checking if all rows are NaN or not `isna()` and `all()`:

```
out=df.iloc[:, [1,10]].isna().all(1)
#OR
#out=df.iloc[:, [1,10]].isnull().all(1)
```

OR

for checking if any row has a NaN or not `isna()` and `any()`:

```
out=df.iloc[:, [1,10]].isna().any(1)
#OR
#out=df.iloc[:, [1,10]].isnull().any(1)
```

Now If you print `out` you will get a boolean series of True and False

For your If statement try:

```
if df.iloc[:, [1,10]].isna().any(1).any():
    print('NaN values')
```

Comment: I tried your code but got the same error. Post edited.

Comment: @luka updated answer...kindly have a look **:)**